# dictionary loop manipulation

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
```

, I want to be able to return like this with loops, while loading from a list:

```
{'chance': {'instance1': '1', 'instance2': '2', 'instance3': '3', 'instance4': '4'}}
```

the list looks like this:

```
pol=["1","2","3","4"]
```

I tried doing it with loops like this:

```
for i in range(1,5):
        for j in range(4):
            print(j)
```

or like this:

```
 for  line in inst['chance']:
        miroute = re.match('instance*', line)
        if miroute:
            for i in range(4):
                print(i)
                break
            print(miroute)
```

but with no success, do you have any idea how to process it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is this:

```py
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
pol=["1","2","3","4"]
d = a['chance']
keys = iter(d.keys())
for p in pol:
    d[next(keys)] = p
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'chance': {'instance1': '1', 'instance2': '2', 'instance3': '3', 'instance4': '4'}}
```

Some help in the docs:

- [dict.keys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)
- [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)
- [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: No need to use `iter(d.keys())` here `iter(d)` works same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way...

```
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
pol=["1","2","3","4"]

b = {'chance': {}}
for x, y in zip(a['chance'], pol):
    b['chance'][x] = y

print(b)

{'chance': {'instance1': '1', 'instance2': '2', 'instance3': '3', 'instance4': '4'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy Way.

```py
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
d =  a['chance']
pol=["1","2","3","4"]
for index,key in enumerate(d.keys()):
    d[key]=pol[index]

print(a)
```

##### OUTPUT

```
{'chance': {'instance1': '1', 'instance2': '2', 'instance3': '3', 'instance4': '4'}}
```

Built-In Function in code: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use `dict comprehension` in the `a["chance"]`

```
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
a["chance"].update({x:str(i) for i,(x,_) in enumerate(a["chance"].items())})
print(a)
```

output:

```
{'chance': {'instance1': '0', 'instance2': '1', 'instance3': '2', 'instance4': '3'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, walking through dictionaries can be tricky, but I highly recommend `f-strings` if you are trying to match up a lot of numbers and strings together:

```
a = {'chance': {}}

for i in range(1,5):
    a['chance'][f'instance{i}'] = i

print(a)
```

```
{'chance': {'instance1': 1, 'instance2': 2, 'instance3': 3, 'instance4': 4}}
```

If you absolutely must start with `a` as you have above, you can still accomplish your with the same code, as it will still write the keys in the same manner:

```
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}

for i in range(1,5):
    a['chance'][f'instance{i}'] = i

print(a)
```

```
{'chance': {'instance1': 1, 'instance2': 2, 'instance3': 3, 'instance4': 4}}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to utilise OP's *pol* list

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the below solution for multiple `'chance'` if you like:

```
>>> a = {'chance1': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''},
     'chance2': {'instance5': '', 'instance6': '', 'instance7': '', 'instance8': ''},}
>>> pol=["1","2","3","4", "5", "6", "7","8"]
>>> {key : {k : pol[f_idx*4+idx] for idx, (k,v) in enumerate(a[key].items())} for f_idx, (key, dct) in enumerate(a.items())}
{'chance1': {'instance1': '1','instance2': '2','instance3': '3','instance4': '4'},
 'chance2': {'instance5': '5','instance6': '6','instance7': '7','instance8': '8'}}
```

You can do this as `one_line`:

```
>>> a['chance'] = {k : pol[idx] for idx, (k,v) in enumerate(a['chance'].items())}
>>> a
{'chance': {'instance1': '1','instance2': '2','instance3': '3','instance4': '4'}}
```

Input:

```
a = {'chance': {'instance1': '', 'instance2': '', 'instance3': '', 'instance4': ''}}
pol=["1","2","3","4"]
```